# What are the symmetries of a principal homogeneous bundle?

Tags: gr.group-theory, dg.differential-geometry, principal-bundles, ct.category-theory, groupoids

Let $\operatorname{Klein}$ denote the category of principal homogeneous bundles. An object in this category is a tuple $\mathbf Q = (Q, P; G, H; q, a, \tilde a)$, where:

- $G$ is a Lie group, and $H$ is a closed subgroup;
- $P$ is a [$G$-torsor](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/torsors.html) and the manifold $Q$ is diffeomorphic to the quotient $G/H$;
- The (left) actions $\tilde a : G \to \operatorname{Aut}(P)$ and $a : G \to \operatorname{Aut}(Q)$ are morphisms of topological groups; and
- $q :P \to Q$ is a principal $H$-bundle.

A morphism $\Phi : \mathbf Q \to \mathbf Q'$ is described by a tuple $\Phi = (\varphi, \tilde \varphi, f)$, where $\varphi : Q \to Q'$ and $\tilde \varphi : P \to P'$ are diffeomorphisms which commute with the bundle maps $q : P \to Q$ and $q' : P' \to Q'$, and $f : G \to G'$ is a morphism of Lie groups mapping $H$ to $H'$, and which satisfies the identity $$\tilde a'_{f(g)} \circ \tilde \varphi = \tilde \varphi \circ \tilde a_g$$ for all $g \in G$.

---

I think that this is the correct categorical description of principal homogeneous bundles; please correct me if I'm wrong. I selected the name $\operatorname{Klein}$ in homage to Felix Klein and his Erlangen Program.

It seems that such a bundle $\mathbf Q$ contains all the data on its symmetries. Namely, I think that its automorphism group $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbf Q)$ is isomorphic to its Lie group Lie group $G = G(\mathbf Q)$?

It is easy to see that there is a natural map $K : G \hookrightarrow \operatorname{Aut}(\mathbf Q)$, in that each $u \in G$ corresponds to a unique automorphism $K_u \in \operatorname{Aut}(\mathbf Q)$. The morphism $K_u = (k_u, \tilde k_u, c_u)$ is defined by $$k_u(q) = a_u(q), \quad \tilde k_u(p) = \tilde a_u(p), \quad \mathrm{and} \quad c_u(g) = ugu^{-1}.$$ That is, the morphism $K_u$ acts by left-multiplication on both $Q$ and $P$, but by left-conjugation on $G$.

- Is this map $K$ surjective? i.e., is $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbf Q)$ isomorphic to $G = G(\mathbf Q)$?

If the answer is yes, then I think that this captures the notion of "internal symmetries" of the bundle, since these are the transformations which preserve the bundle structure.

However, I know that groupoids also show up to describe symmetries in a categorical setting, and I would be interested to hear more on that point of view.

- How can groupoids be used to describe symmetries in this category?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, in general $G=G(\mathbf{Q})$ can be strictly smaller that ${\rm Aut}(\mathbf{Q})$.

Let $G$ be a Lie group and $H\subset G$ be a Lie subgroup. Set $P=G$, $\ Q=G/H$, and define the maps  in the obvious way. We get a principal homogeneous bundle $\mathbf{Q}=(Q,P,\dots)$ in your sense.

Now take $G=SL(n,\mathbb{C})$, $\ H=SO(n,\mathbb{C})$. Consider the automorphism $\tau$ of $G$ given by $\tau(g)= (g^T)^{-1}$, there $g^T$ denotes the transpose of $g$. Since $\tau$ takes $H$ to itself, it induces an automorphism of the principal homogeneous bundle $\mathbf{Q}$. It is well known that for $n\ge 3$, the automorphism $\tau$ of $G$ is *not inner*, i.e. is not of the form $c_u(g)=ugu^{-1}$, which gives the negative answer to your question.

Comment: Oh yes, I should have caught that! Thank you so much for the good example, @Mikhail Borovoi.

Answer (score 2):

Did you have a look at parabolic geometries.
Your description reminds me of the flat models of parabolic geometries.

MR1352565 (96k:16039). Andreas Cap, Jan Slovak:
Parabolic Geometries I: Background and General Theory.
Mathematical Surveys and Monographs 154, Amer. Math. Soc. 2009, 628 pp.

Here $H$ is assumed to be a parabolic subgroup of a semisimple or reductive group $G$;
you can do an astonishing amount of things with this.

A little more general, look at Cartan connections.

Answer (score 1):

The OP asks: How can groupoids be used to describe symmetries in this category? Here are some suggestions for 
starting.

A principal $G$-bundle $E \to B$ can also be desribed as a groupoid $P= EE^{-1}$ over $B$, a construction due to C. Ehresmann. Here $P(b,c)$ is the set of $G$-maps $E_b \to E_{c}$. So one may ask: what for groupoids generalises the well known inner automorphism map $G \to Aut (G)$ for a group $G$?

Now the category $Gpd$ of abstract groupoids is cartesian closed, this is one aspect of the utility  of groupoids. We can write the exponential law as a bijection 
$$Gpd(G \times H,K) \cong Gpd(G, GPD(H,K)).$$
The objects of $GPD(H,K)$ are the morphisms, or functors, $H \to K$ and the arrows of $GPD(H,K)$ are the natural equivalences of functors. In the case of groups, these are just conjugacies of morphisms.

So for any groupoid $G$ there is an endomorphism object $END(G)$ which is a monoid object in groupoids, and this has a maximal subgroup object $AUT(G)$ which is a group object in the category of groupoids. However as shown in the paper available [here](http://pages.bangor.ac.uk/~mas010/pdffiles/brown-spenmcer-G-groupoid.pdf), group objects in groupoids are equivalent to crossed modules, and the crossed module one obtains by this process is of the form $d: S(G) \to Aut(G)$ where is $S(G)$ is the group of *admissible sections* $\sigma$ of $G$ as defined by Ehresmann in his paper on topological and differentiable categories. Such a $\sigma $ is a section of say the source map $s$ such that $t\sigma$ is a bijection on $Ob(G)$. These have a multiplication defined by Ehresmann: $\sigma \tau (x)= \sigma (t\tau x) \tau)x)$ (or analogous, depending on conventions conventions). (Such $\sigma$ are called *bisections* in Mackenzie, K.C.H., *General theory of Lie groupoids and Lie algebroids*, London Mathematical Society Lecture Note Series, Volume 213. Cambridge University Press, Cambridge (2005). )

Can one use this framework to study the differentiable, or Lie, case?

I may be able to add more later.